# Average of a tensor with respect to a group action

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors, differential-forms, pullback

Consider a smooth manifold $M$ (assume it boundary-free and orientable) and a tensor field $\mathcal{G}\in\Gamma(\otimes^hTM\otimes^kT^*M)$. Let $\Phi:\mathbb{T}^p\times M \rightarrow M$ be a torus action on the manifold. What is the definition of the average of the tensor $\mathcal{G}$ with respect to the action $\Phi$?

I think it should be defined as
$$ \bar{\mathcal{G}} = \frac{1}{\int_M d\alpha}\int_M (\Phi_{\alpha})^*\mathcal{G}\;d\alpha_1\wedge ... \wedge d\alpha_p. $$
Is my intuition correct? It seems at least to be coherent with the fact that when $\mathcal{G}$ is invariant with respect to the torus action, then $(\Phi_\alpha)^*\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{G}$ and hence $\bar{\mathcal{G}}=\mathcal{G}$ as expected.

Comment: What are the $\alpha_i$? You certainly cannot integrate over $M$. Where did $\Bbb T^p$ go?

Comment: Yes, I have now understood that I should integrate over the torus. The $\alpha_i$s are angular coordinates on $\mathbb{T}^p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably average it with respect to the action (but your integral is over $M$). If $G \circlearrowright M$ is a smooth action, $G$ is compact Lie group, $\nu$ the Haar (probability) measure on $G$ and we also denote by $g$ the map $M \ni p \mapsto g\cdot p \in M$, it seems that $$\overline{\mathcal{G}}_x(\theta^1,\ldots, \theta^h, X_1,\ldots, X_k) = \int_{G} (g^*\mathcal{G})_x(\theta^1,\ldots, \theta^h, X_1,\ldots, X_k)\,{\rm d}\nu(g)$$makes more sense, where $x \in M$, $\theta^i \in T_x^*M$ and $X_j \in T_xM$ for all $1 \leq i \leq h$ and $1 \leq j \leq k$ are all fixed. Then we have that $g^*\overline{\mathcal{G}} = \overline{\mathcal{G}}$ for all $g \in G$, by construction.

Comment: Ok, so in my case I should integrate over the $p-$torus, which makes sense since in my case I'm integrating the pull-back against the standard volume form of the torus. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes! If you average by trying to integrate over $M$ you don't even get a tensor field anymore! (I'm implictly assuming that you want the average of a tensor field on $M$ to be another tensor field on $M$, which is now invariant under the action). And since $\nu(G) = 1$, if you average $\overline{\mathcal{G}}$ again, nothing changes.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, it makes sense now. Furthermore, I don't have a great experience with integration on manifolds so my question is : if I need to compute the Lie derivative along $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ of $\bar{\mathcal{G}}$, can I take the Lie derivative inside the sign of integral since it is on a fixed domain and it is bounded?

Comment: You can differentiate under the integral, yes. Since $G$ is compact and $\mathcal{L}_X$ does not "touch" $G$ at all everything works out nicely.

Comment: Perfect, your comments are very helpful. Thanks.